# Not able to connect to sftp from wso2 MI Proxy service using pem/ppk file

Tags: wso2, sftp, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

`I am trying to connect to my sftp server using PEM file from wso2 MI proxy service but I am not able to connect to it, if I use password based connection it is working fine. Please find below the proxy service which I am using,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="FileProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="$body" name="FILE_CONTENT" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log>
                <property expression="get-property('FILE_CONTENT')" name="[FileProxy] File content"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:sftp://user@11.22.333.44/home/user/wso2/text.csv?transport.vfs.AvoidPermissionCheck=true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentity">/home/user/wso2/test_key.pem</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPUserDirIsRoot">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.csv</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">NONE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:sftp://user@11.22.333.44/home/user/wso2/failure?transport.vfs.AvoidPermissionCheck=true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">NONE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:sftp://user@11.22.333.44/home/user/wso2/failure?transport.vfs.AvoidPermissionCheck=true</parameter>   
</proxy>
```

`

`I am getting below error when trying to connect to sftp server,

```
[2023-03-14 12:46:50,719] ERROR {VFSTransportListener} - Repeatedly failed to resolve the file URI: sftp://user@11.22.333.44/home/user/wso2/text.csv?transport.vfs.AvoidPermissionCheck=true org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://user@11.22.333.44/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:86)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:149)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:111)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:81)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:778)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:658)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:262)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:189)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:135)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "11.22.333.44".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:164)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:79)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:162)
    ... 14 more
```

Can someone help me with this?

`

Comment: Does it work when you directly connect with certificate-based authentication without WSO2?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the above issue : The path which is mentioned in the "transport.vfs.SFTPIdentity" was wrong. In the server for sftp, /home/user was the default so no need to mention that explicitly.